# Failed to Restore bak files to SqlServer with error 'There is insufficient free space on disk volume ...', there's enough space on it

Tags: c#, sql-server

Here is the situation.

I have a Database DB1 on SQL server Server1.

I backup DB1 to db1.bak, and then I try to restore DB1.bak back to Server1 with a different name DB2.

I'm using C# to do this job, but it fails. Restoring will be successfully if I don't resotre DB1.bak back to the same sql-server with a different name and with the orignal database exists.

I can also restore successfully using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio.
Here is the SQL generated from my C# program.

```
SET @RestoreSQL = '
RESTORE DATABASE [DB2] FROM  DISK = N''e:\Temp\DB1.bak'' WITH  FILE = 1, 
MOVE N''CtrlSys'' TO N''E:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.LATIN1_2012\MSSQL\DATA\DB2Sys.mdf'',
MOVE N''CtrlData'' TO N''E:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.LATIN1_2012\MSSQL\DATA\DB2Data.ndf'',
MOVE N''CtrlIx'' TO N''E:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.LATIN1_2012\MSSQL\DATA\DB2Ix.ndf'',
MOVE N''CtrlLog'' TO N''E:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.LATIN1_2012\MSSQL\DATA\DB2Log.ldf'',
NOUNLOAD,  REPLACE,  STATS = 10'
exec (@RestoreSQL)
```

Here is the error:

```
Msg 3257, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
There is insufficient free space on disk volume 'E:\' to create the database. 

The database requires 86240788480 additional free bytes, while only 83155132416 bytes are available.

Msg 3119, Level 16, State 4, Line 2

Problems were identified while planning for the RESTORE statement. Previous messages  provide details.

Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 2

RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally
```

Comment: Besides I used C# generate the whole SQL then execute it. Is there any better way to do this? I'm using SQL server 2012. Thanks!

Comment: How have you determined "there's enough space on it". The error message clearly indicates there isn't. Are you disputing the `86240788480` or `83155132416`?

Comment: Note that `bak` files can be compressed. Then free up at least 3085656064 bytes.

Comment: Oh I see I missed the line "I can also restore successfully using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio"

Comment: There was still more than 70Gb space. So that shouldn't be space problem.

Comment: Are you sure that the restoring by the SSMS is performing to the same disk? By default the SSMS performing the restore to the path where the source DB files were placed.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in your C# script. You restoring 4 files:

> CtrlSys => E:\...\MSSQL\DATA\DB2.mdf
>
> CtrlData => E:\...\MSSQL\DATA\DB2.ndf
>
> CtrlIx => E:\...\MSSQL\DATA\DB2.ndf
>
> CtrlLog => E:\...\MSSQL\DATA\DB2.ldf

But the files `CtrlData` and `CtrlIx` you trying to restore in the same file. Try to change the file name for the one of them.

Comment: Sorry, I attached wrong code, it should be : CtrlSys => E:\...\MSSQL\DATA\DB2Sys.mdf CtrlData => E:\...\MSSQL\DATA\DB2Data.ndf CtrlIx => E:\...\MSSQL\DATA\DB2Ix.ndf CtrlLog => E:\...\MSSQL\DATA\DB2Log.ldf